# No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{}' - Typescript compiler error

Tags: typescript, object

I have an object with a nested object value and I want to reverse the key-value pair. My code works just in plain javascript but I get a compile error in Typescript.

This is the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{}'.

Please advice.

[Typescriplt playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jgYQK5gBiwEANgCYDOAMsJWMgN4BQyyw5A-AFzIh4BbAEbQA3K2QA5OAIi96UUAHNxzAL7NmCAPYh6yclji8AShB1RyAHgXKANGkzZ8REhRp0wAPmQBeJhJsAESGzgQAtACMQbwsbPHxQRwxyACsdoEJyEHSsilBTogEyNEZWfGZamWJobgRAEwpceXZybwA7NXlOTIQ%20YUIxY1dyJUjIUYu4QDMTZkJSeQpABwjC7l9vAVGgwyzI1WZE2Fg4QAscy2tS7yR9WuJG-07xRcH47VTqZctiymR6Xmj16z2wuzSQRGYyOnwiADYft02iU4Q9gk8tgNigj3kDgrDTu1EVkenlMS8GESDupNDo9NpSBAAHSkbRKAAUAHkhAArcxgJkQcCKCCUdm1ACUTKgEHIeCQ7PZiAQDgA2gBrCAATwcADc4KQ8BAALoSvw%20JUIBCq-WG5kcACExr8yE1OuQyolDkYaglEtEQA)

Expected Output:

```
{
  "5": "dataCut-1",
  "7": "dataCut-2",
  "8": "dataCut-3",
  "12": "dataCut-4",
  "15": "dataCut-5",
  "16": "dataCut-6",
  "undefined": "dataCut-7"
}
```

Comment: You need to give the initial object a explicit type as otherwise it is inferred as just `{}` when used as your accumulator argument. In this case looks like `Record<string, string>` would work. Eg: `data.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[value.id!] = key, acc), {} as Record<string, string>)`.

Comment: I encourage you to not mutate `accumulator`. If you use `reduce`, I assume that you are trying to make it in functional way.
Consider this example: `{...acc, [id]: key }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you need to annotate more.

I also want to add that you should not use `!` to silence type checking. It's warning you about the possibility of having an undefined key, which is what you have explicitly defined your interface to allow and which actually exist in your data set.

Your output will include `undefined: 'dataCut-7'`

The following snippet discards entries which don't have and id, but of course you can deal with them any way you like, as long as you do deal with them.

```js
Object.entries(data).reduce((acc:Record<string, string>, [key, value]) => {
    if(value.id) acc[value.id] = key;
    return acc
}, {});
```